# Java Applets- creating a interactive traffic light without using 'canvas'?

Tags: java, applet

To make it short I want to design a java applet that shows a traffic light with three adjacent buttons. One that says red light, one that says amber light and one for green.

---

My problem is: is that I don't know how to link each button with the right oval. All of the ovals belong to the same Graphics variable g. If I change the color all three would be changed.

There is a superclass called canvas that helps separate each object in its own entity from my knowledge but I know there is an easier way.

How can I do this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.applet.Applet;

public class Traffic extends Applet
    implements ActionListener
{

    int colourNum; //global variable which is responible for changing the light

    Button bttn1 = new Button ("Stop Traffic");
    Button bttn2 = new Button ("Caution");
    Button bttn3 = new Button ("Proceed");

    public void init ()
    {
        setBackground (Color.lightGray);

        bttn1.addActionListener (this); // stop light
        bttn2.addActionListener (this); // yellow light
        bttn3.addActionListener (this); // green light

        add (bttn1);
        add (bttn2);
        add (bttn3);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)  // responsible for graphics "within" the window
    {
        g.setColor (Color.black);

        switch (colourNum)
        {
            case 1:
                g.setColor (Color.red);
                break;
        }
        g.fillOval (30, 40, 20, 20); // red light
        g.fillOval (30, 70, 20, 20); // yello light
        g.fillOval (30, 100, 20, 20); // green light
    }


    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt.getSource () == bttn1)
            colourNum = 1;
        else if (evt.getSource () == bttn2)
            colourNum = 2;
        else
            colourNum = 3;

        repaint ();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should avoid overriding paint on top level containers like Appet. You should also be calling super.paint to honour the paint chain

Comment: It would be better to create new `Canvas`-based components to individually handle the painting of the traffic signals.

Comment: The best strategy might be to have a `TrafficLights` class that knows how to draw itself and its state (e.g. red, green, blinking yellow.  When it comes time to draw it.  Call `TrafficLights.draw(Graphics)` from within paint in order to paint the current state.

Comment: BTW - Why AWT rather than Swing? (last millennium)  Why an `Applet` rather than a `Frame` or `JFrame`?  (easier)

Comment: SWT is overrated Andrew...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void paint (Graphics g)  // responsible for graphics "within" the window
{
    g.setColor (Color.black);

    g.setColor(colourNum == 1? Color.red : Color.red.darker().darker());
    g.fillOval (30, 40, 20, 20); // red light
    g.setColor(colourNum == 2? Color.yellow : Color.yellow.darker().darker());
    g.fillOval (30, 70, 20, 20); // yello light
    g.setColor(colourNum == 3? Color.green : Color.green.darker().darker());
    g.fillOval (30, 100, 20, 20); // green light
}
```